# MySQL and php will not work

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have tried many ways to implement php and mysql interactivity on my apache server, php seems to work ok and mysql works fine by itself at the terminal, but every time use it to interact with MySQL, it returns a blank page.
Here is one of the links I have tried to use as an example. I have saved it as either test.php or test.html each time showing nothing. I have correctly entered my user and pass, but just will not show.
http://www.anyexample.com/programming/php/php_mysql_example__display_table_as_html.xml

BTW apache shows php scripts without db functions perfectly.

Comment: Post YOUR code. not a link to a tutorial.

Comment: Please show how you set up the database tables. And show the configuration in that php file!

Comment: A blank page when writing PHP code is usually the result of a fatal error with error display turned off. Add this `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors',1);` to the top of your PHP page and see if it shows you your error.

Comment: @cillosis thx for that, that at least called an error rather than nothing.

Comment: @DamianStelucir What error did you get?

Answer (score 1):

I hope when you say "apache shows PHP scripts" it actually means it runs it, not show the code. for your question there, as cillosis and Paul said you need to post your code and errors recieved for us to help you.

for starters let review. are you using the correct SQL Username and Password? also are you Connecting to the proper Database and Table "are they even existing in your database?".

also please check whether your Xampp/wampp/lampp or others is actually running.

also check if your apache is running.

also please save files with PHP and SQL codes as .php not .html.

if all of this is running and your'e connecting to the proper database and all, also if your file is saved as .php, then the problem should lie in your code. ergo you really should post it. :)